# How to autorun a script in usb flash drive on Ubuntu without root authentication

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, usb-drive

This year I started a cybersecurity course
and the teacher (who has Ubuntu) challenged us students to steal his data with a USB flash drive.
He didn't specify what type of data, so I chose to use this approach:

```
cp -r "/home/" "$(pwd)"
```

but the professor poses a further problem:
he claims that the script.sh will automatically steal the data as soon as the pendrive is inserted WITHOUT REQUESTS FOR CONFIRMATION and ROOT AUTHENTICATION.

From what I know (correct me if I'm wrong), autorun on Linux is not really a thing.

That's why I'm in crisis.

Doing research I found (again, correct me if I'm wrong) the `rc.local` file but from what I understand it is no longer supported.

I ask you first of all if it is something feasible, and if so, how this happens.

PS: Sorry for any mistakes, English is not my mother tongue, plus I'm a beginner.

Answer (score -1):

Linux itself does not autorun scripts on the USB drive. The Ubuntu *desktop* may autorun the script `autorun.sh`. So, don't use the desktop. Logout and use the console (alt-f1).

To steal his data, don't mount the USB-drive but use `dd if=/dev/sdb of=~/stolen_data` (replace `sdb` with the real device). Then operate on your copy. Mount via loopback. See if there are multiple partitions. Et cetera.

Comment: He shall steal **with** the USB drive, not **from**, as far as I understand.

Comment: I completely misread the question.